# Trying to connect to a Phoenix channel, but getting SOCKET is undefined

Tags: angularjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm a newbie in **Phoenix** and I was trying to learn **Channels**.

My frontend which is in **Angularjs** run on port **:3000**. And my backend which run on port **:4000**.

I am getting an error of **Socket is not defined**.

**index.html**

```
<script src="/node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js"></script>


<script>
var socket = new Socket("ws://localhost:4000", {
  logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) }),
  transport: WebSocket
});
socket.connect();</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like `phoenix.js` does not exist at that path. Can you check the path?

Comment: @Dogbert yes sir i double checked it. its there

Comment: Is your socket connection url ok? How about `"ws://localhost:4000/socket"`? Are you using a local setup, so you can really reach `localhost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon directly including the `phoenix.js` file via `script`-Tag, you will need to use the `window.Phoenix` object which includes all exported `phoenix` modules

```
<script>
var socket = new Phoenix.Socket("ws://localhost:4000", {
  logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) }),
  transport: WebSocket
});
socket.connect();
</script>
```

Included in `window.Phoenix`:

- `Ajax`
- `LongPoll`
- `Presence`
- `Socket`
- `Channel`